# definition of affine normed space

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces, affine-geometry

1.What is the precise definition of affine normed space?Do there exist normed spaces which are not affine?

2.Suppose $V$ is normed space,according to the absract definition of affine space,there must exist a set $A$ together with a vector space V with a transitive free action of $V$ on $A$.What is the set $A$,is $A=V$ as a set?

3.Is every Euclidean space a aafine normed space?

Comment: I guess it is just an affine space, associated to a vector space that comes with a norm. The *true* notion is that of a "normed vector space", its affine counterpart is not deep.

Comment: I think $A$ could be any set, you might take $A=V$, but the fact that $V$ acts on itself turns $V$ into an affine space, the notion of the action of the additive group of the normed vector space on the "point-space" is crucial

Comment: @Peter Melech,does $A$ has a relationship with $V$?

Comment: @math112358 Yes, the free action of $(V,+)$ on $A$ is the relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subset $A$ of a vector space $V$ is called *affine* if it satisfies any of the following equivalent conditions:

- There is a $p \in A$ such that the set $A - p := \{v -p\mid v \in A\}$ is a vector subspace of $V$.
- For every $p \in A$, the set $A - p$ is a vector subspace of $V$.
- For every pair of points $p, q \in A$ and $t$ in the field of $V$, $tp + (1-t)q \in A$. That is, if $A$ contains two points, it also contains the line running through them.

You could develop the concept of "affine" without reference to a vector space. Euclid did that for real affine spaces of 1, 2, and 3 dimensions over two thousand years ago. He called them "lines", "planes" and "space", respectively. But generally, it is nicer to have a ready-made linear structure built-in instead of having to create one from a bunch of geometric axioms.

Note that any vector space is automatically affine. More generally if $U$ is subspace of $V$ and $p \in V$, then $U + p$ is an affine space.

There is no such thing as a "normed affine space", as "norm" refers to the distance from a point to the origin, and affine spaces do not contain an origin or any other distinguished point. There is no property of the affine space itself that will differentiate between two points within it. The only way to identify a specific point in an affine space is by reference to the containing vector space. However, if the vector space $V$ has a norm, then there is a metric on any affine subspace, measuring the distance between any two points in the affine space.

Comment: I wonder whether the definition you mentioned above is equivalent to the following definition.See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379724/on-affine-spaces-distances-angles-and-coordinates?r=SearchResults

Comment: It is equivalent. My definition is a specific instantiation of that definition. The vector space $V$ in my definition and that one differ. Let me call mine $\hat V$, which is just some larger extension of $V$. They allow $A$ to be an arbitrary set, and then must define a compatible addition from $A\times V \to A$. I require $A \subset \hat V$ such that $A + V = A$. The addition they need is thus satisfied. My method may seem more restrictive, but in fact, you can always define such a $\hat V$ from their definition, so it really isn't.

Comment: If $A$ is an arbitrary set,when we talk about the Euclidean space $\Bbb R^n$,what does $A$ stand for?

Comment: $A$ doesn't stand for anything until you define it. Can you please explain a little more about what you are asking?

Comment: I mean that how to check that $\Bbb R^n$ is an affine space by using the the abstract definition(the form of a triple $(A,V,\phi)$.)

Comment: For any vector space $V$, you can always let $A = V$, and the addition is just vector addition in $V$. This meets all the conditions in that definition, which makes the vector space $V$ an affine space.

Comment: Oh,I see.Thanks vslery much!